# How to get a simple SimpleXMLElement value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm aware of how to drill down into the nodes of an xml document as described here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

but am at a loss on how to extract the value in the following example

```
$xmlStr = '<Error>Hello world. There is an Error</Error>';
$xml    = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) returns an object of type `SimpleXMLElement` whose properties will have the data of the `XML` string.

In your case there is no opening `<xml>` and closing `</xml>` tags, which every valid `XML` should have.

If these were present then to get the data between `<Error>` tags you can do:

```
$xmlStr = '<xml><Error>Hello world. There is an Error</Error></xml>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
echo $xml->Error; // prints "Hello world. There is an Error"
```

Comment: Yeap, that makes sense. The original xml is invalid as it missed the xml tags hence I couldn't do $xml->Error in my original question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: In the case where you are dealing with invalid xml (as I was), echo $xml; would suffice if you wanted to echo out the error :)

Comment: @superspace: You are correct. But its better to keep XML as valid :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you know. The value of the tag is just:

```
$error = $xml;
```

Thanks for looking :)